# Converting FoxPro FXP file to PRG

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have lost PRG files.  How do I convert foxPro FXP files to PRG ?
Is there any free tool to convert FXP file ?  I can't find any free tool.
Is there any way to convert ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are tools but AFAIK none of them is for free.

Comment: ReFox is the one most commonly used by FP/VFP developers, but it is not Free.  Also you could look at:   https://www.google.com/search?q=foxpro+decompiler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: A couple of things come to mind.  FIRST - You say: "I can't find any free tool"   Then you must not be SERIOUS about Decompiling the code.   If something is BUSINESS CRITICAL, you should be willing to spend the money to get the CRITICAL results - buy the Decompiler or Hire a Consultant.  SECOND:  The results of using a decompiler are not "pretty".  It may functionally work, but the objects, variables, etc. are what the Decompiler wanted to name them and not necessarily something that is intuitive.  THIRD  Legality.  If you don't OWN the Source Code (lost or not) then Decompiling it is ILLEGAL.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you're looking for is called a "decompiler".  If you search on that, you'll find some.